# Include js dependencies in kotlin-js

Tags: javascript, gradle, kotlin, kotlin-js

I want to incude javascript dependencies in my kotlinjs project. (concret : https://airbnb.io/polyglot.js/ but others as well).

My kotlinjs Project is a gradle Project, developed in IntelliJ Idea.

I've searched one day now, but I wasn't able to find any clue, how I can add this dependency and work with the methods from the js library.

Is it even possible? It should, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

[kotlin-frontend-plugin](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-frontend-plugin) can add npm dependencies from Gradle:

```
kotlinFrontend {
    npm {
        dependency "style-loader" // production dependency
        devDependency "karma"     // development dependency
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the frontend plugin obsolete?